# HoloLens OS sound effects

Tags: hololens

I searched the entire internet looking for the sound effects of the operating system from the Microsoft HoloLens headset. When I watched a video about the next assembly of hololens wasps, I suddenly realized for myself that I really want to get the sounds: opening, closing applications. How to do it or find it?

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eXdlcrvqg40

This is my first question on StackOverflow and sorry for the my translator :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interactive sound effects of HoloLens are built into the operating system, and currently, there is no way to get the audio files through the file explorer. If you want to use Mixed Reality-Style sound effects in your own HoloLens App, we suggest you take a look at audio files provided by MRTK: https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/StandardAssets/Audio. Under Microsoft's open-source license, you can obtain a copy of the audio assets from MRTK to use.